# Jasper compilation error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError it/businesslogic/ireport/IReportScriptlet

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Can you please guide which jar file need to be included to resolve this error in jasper compilation env. I am using iReport version 3.7.6

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  it/businesslogic/ireport/IReportScriptlet 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included  iReport-1.3.1.jar file and issue vanished